# Nice looking UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

I'm trying to make a nice looking UIButton. I'm not exactly sure what I mean by that, but something nicer than just a plain white looking rounded corner button with blue font. I can't seem to find anything online, so can anyone help? I want to do it all by programming (no XIB) and I am not an artist so I can't draw any custom images or anything like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back in May of last year, Jeff LaMarche (of iPhone dev shop Martian Craft and co-author of several iPhone development books) put out a suite called [GradientButtons](http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/) that makes it easy to implement pretty, shiny, colorful buttons. I've used it in several projects and it's quite nice.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tutorial on how to make a shhiny button all in code, no image needed!

[Tutorial on gradients at CocoaWithLove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://tapadoo.com/2010/tired-of-trying-to-create-nice-buttons-for-your-iphone-app-try-this/

I ran into the above link when I was searching for a similar resource. Did the job

Answer (score 0):

The Apple UI guidelines would suggest I think that you use the standard button unless you have good reason not to.

Comment: That's true for most Cocoa Touch controls, but the standard round-rect UIButton looks terrible. You are supposed to customize the look. Apple's apps only use it in Settings-like views. Many of Apple's sample apps include custom images for buttons.